# How can i update my array list data values?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following class where my arraylist is kept:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Theatre {

private ArrayList<Room> theatres;

public Theatre(){
    theatres = new ArrayList<Room>();
    theatres.add(new Room("Theatre 1", 120));
    theatres.add(new Room("Theatre 2", 180));
    theatres.add(new Room("Theatre 3", 100));
    theatres.add(new Room("Theatre 4", 120));
    theatres.add(new Room("Theatre 5", 200));
    theatres.add(new Room("Theatre 6", 180));
    theatres.add(new Room("Theatre 7", 80));
    theatres.add(new Room("Theatre 8", 50));
    theatres.add(new Room("Theatre 9", 120));
    theatres.add(new Room("Theatre 10", 150));

}

public void addTheatre(String theatreName, int seatsAvailable){
    Room t = new Room(theatreName, seatsAvailable);
}

public void printTheatres(){
    for (int index=0; index<theatres.size(); index++)
    {
    System.out.println(theatres.get(index));
}
   }

public void updateSeats(){
    int numSelected = Basket.seatsBooked;
    int userFilmSelection = MainActivity.filmSelectionNumber;

    theatres.get(userFilmSelection).setSeatsAvailable(theatres.get(userFilmSelection).getSeatsAvailable() - numSelected);
}


public int getSeats(){
    int theatre = 0;
    int userFilmSelection = MainActivity.filmSelectionNumber;

    theatre = theatres.get(userFilmSelection).getSeatsAvailable();
    Basket.theatre+=theatres.get(userFilmSelection).getTheatreName();

    return theatre;
}

}
```

I would like a way to update the seats in this arraylist, when they are added to the basket from my GUI class. How can i do this. In my GUI i have the following but it seems to lose the number of seats each time i go back to the MainActivity order screen. I think this is because im creating a new Theatre object each time but dont know how to get around this.

I need the method below to return the current number of seats available after they have been updated so i can output to GUI.

```
public int getSeats(){
    Theatre t = new Theatre();
    t.updateSeats();
    return t.getSeats();
}
```

The code works because i have tried it in java IDE called blue j that allows me to see objects but doesnt in here and most likely because im creating the new object each time.

**UPDATE**
This should be returning the updated number of seats but doesnt.

```
public int getSeats(){
        Theatre.updateSeats();
        return Theatre.getSeats();
    }
```

Comment: `"I think this is because im creating a new Theatre object each time but dont know how to get around this."` -- create a non-static private Theatre field perhaps and only deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `getSeats()` is a `Theatre` method, then

```
public int getSeats(){
    Theatre t = new Theatre();
    t.updateSeats();
    return t.getSeats();
}
```

is creating a new instance every call, and so you are using new data every time.
The method you posted first

```
public int getSeats(){
    int theatre = 0;
    int userFilmSelection = MainActivity.filmSelectionNumber;

    theatre = theatres.get(userFilmSelection).getSeatsAvailable();
    Basket.theatre+=theatres.get(userFilmSelection).getTheatreName();

    return theatre;
}
```

seems fine if called after `updateSeats()`.
I'm not sure if I completely understood your question.

Ok, if you need your `Room`s to be always available you may want to declare the `List` as `static`

```
private static final List<Room> theatres;

static {
   theatres = new ArrayList<>(10);
   theatres.add(new Room("Theatre 1", 120));
   theatres.add(new Room("Theatre 2", 180));
   theatres.add(new Room("Theatre 3", 100));
   theatres.add(new Room("Theatre 4", 120));
   theatres.add(new Room("Theatre 5", 200));
   theatres.add(new Room("Theatre 6", 180));
   theatres.add(new Room("Theatre 7", 80));
   theatres.add(new Room("Theatre 8", 50));
   theatres.add(new Room("Theatre 9", 120));
   theatres.add(new Room("Theatre 10", 150));
}

public Theatre(){
   // Nothing here
}
```

I reworked what you did, see if you understand.

```
public class Room
{
   private String _name;
   private int _seats;

   public Room(final String name, final int seats) {
      _name = name;
      _seats = seats;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return _name;
   }

   public int getAvailableSeats() {
      return _seats;
   }

   public void setName(final String name) {
      _name = name;
   }

   public void setAvailableSeats(final int seats) {
      _seats = seats;
   }
}

public class Theatre
{
   private static final List<Room> ROOMS;

   static {
      ROOMS = new ArrayList<Room>(10);
      ROOMS.add(new Room("Room 1", 120));
      ROOMS.add(new Room("Room 2", 180));
      ROOMS.add(new Room("Room 3", 100));
      ROOMS.add(new Room("Room 4", 120));
      ROOMS.add(new Room("Room 5", 200));
      ROOMS.add(new Room("Room 6", 180));
      ROOMS.add(new Room("Room 7", 80));
      ROOMS.add(new Room("Room 8", 50));
      ROOMS.add(new Room("Room 9", 120));
      ROOMS.add(new Room("Room 10", 150));
   }

   public static void addRoom(final String roomName, final int seatsAvailable) {
      ROOMS.add(new Room(roomName, seatsAvailable));
   }

   public static void printRooms() {
      for (final Room room : ROOMS) {
         System.out.println(room.getName());
      }
   }

   public static void updateSeats() {
      final Room room = ROOMS.get(MainActivity.filmSelectionNumber);
      room.setAvailableSeats(room.getAvailableSeats() - Basket.seatsBooked);
   }

   public static int getSeats() {
      final Room room = ROOMS.get(MainActivity.filmSelectionNumber);
      Basket.theatre += room.getName();

      return room.getAvailableSeats();
   }
}
```

Comment: The first method `getSeats()` is in my GUI which returns the number of seats so that it can be output via one of the components i have. I need a way to avoid creating new objects each time as it destroys the data.

Comment: But then how would i update the seats depending on user input.

Comment: ROOMS is in capital letters just because it is a "costant" (static and final).

Comment: The method in my GUI still doesnt seem to be returning the updated number of seats. See my code above please.

Comment: It depends on how you implemented the assignement of MainActivity.filmSelectionNumber. You should debug your code, by doing so you'll discover what you're missing

Comment: Thanks for the help. much appreciated